# How to perform comparisons on numpy arrays (from netCDF files) using python?

Tags: python, comparison, netcdf

I'm writing a python script that reads two different netCDF files and, after performing an evaluation on the variables makes some calculation, the idea is (an example of the idea of the code the real one is too long):

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
#other modules loaded...

#Values
a = 2
b = 4
c = 1

def srf(r, h):
    if r[:] == 2:
        if h[:] > 0:
            surf = 1 + b
        else:
            surf = a + b 
    else:
        surf = a - c

return surf

path_file : /home/file.nc
fhp = Dataset(path_file, r+)
ra = fhp.variables['VAR'][:]
path_file2 : /home/file2.nc
fhp2 = Dataset(path_file2, r+)
hu = fhp2.variables['VAR2'][:]   

#Call the Function
srf(ra, hu)
```

The netCDF files each have 3 dimensions, if I try to run this code I get this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I need the function to be perform in the las two dimensions that are the ones containing the information to check in a domain [TSTEP, ROW, COL]. So I would need to loop through the dimensions, but I'm not sure how to do it and I don't know if maybe there is an easiest way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is unrelated to netCDF, but is rather about the manipulation numpy arrays, obtained from a netCDF file.

The problem is that given a numpy vector `r`,  `r[:] == 2` (or `r[:] > 0` for that matter) returns a boolean array and not a single boolean. It should therefore not be used in an `if` construction. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you can use following approaches,

- use `(r[:] == 2).any()` or  `(r[:] == 2).all()` instead
- use more complex indexing, for instance,

  ```
  import numpy as np

  def srf(r, h):
      mask_r = (r[:] == 2)
      mask_h = (h[:] > 0)
      surf  = np.ones(r.shape)*(a-c)
      surf[mask_r&mask_h] = 1 + b
      surf[mask_r&(~mask_h)] = a + b
      return surf
  ```

please refer to the numpy documentation about [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more details. This approach is significantly more efficient then loops over indices in python and should be used instead when possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, the second approach was the one I needed. Appreciate your recommendations.

Comment: Also, updated the title of the question given your clarification

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to apply a function along a particular axis, you can use numpy.apply_along_axis.

For example, if you wanted to apply function srf along the time axis, you would do

import numpy as np
srf_arr = np.apply_along_axis(srf, axisnumber, arrayname)